# Include content of CSS file in twig

Tags: css, twig, less

Let's say I use Webpack, and builded a Css file properly at "build/theme/mail.css".
I wants to include the CONTENT of this File  into my twig.

`{% include "https://mysite.io/build/theme/mail.css" %}` doesn't work saying it can't find the file ( but it exist).

I don't want that because im using an inliner, and absolutly need the #CONTENT in my twig.

Comment: Have you tried with `source()` ?

Comment: Yes, and doesn't works

Comment: Place the CSS file into your view folder and then include

Comment: I use webpack so the css file is in the build folder, it would be simplier to put in view folder ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried the File get Content, didn't works. Found a solution:

```
twig:
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/public': public
```

Add a twig path to public directory

and then use :

```
        {% apply inline_css(source(theme_asset('@public/build/theme/email.css'))) %}
```

and add a webpackconfig to build the scss file into public/build

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

You could create **custom twig extension** and use **file_get_contents**.

Extension:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class GetPublicFileContentExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    /** @var string */
    private $publicPath;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
    {
        $this->publicPath = $parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/';
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_public_file_content', [$this, 'getPublicFileContent']),
        ];
    }

    public function getPublicFileContent(string $filepath)
    {
        return file_get_contents($this->publicPath . $filepath);
    }
}
```

Twig:

```
{{ get_public_file_content('build/theme/mail.css') }}
```